# Python: Merging two lists and present them as a string

Tags: python, list, merge, zip

I've done my research and got very close to solving my issue but I need a bit of help to cross the finish line!

I have two lists:

```
Countries = ["Germany", "UK", "France", "Italy"]
Base = ["2005","1298",1222","3990"]
```

Expected outcome:

```
"Germany (2005)", "UK (1298)", "France (1222)", "Italy (3990)"
```

My script:

```
zipped = zip(Countries, Base)
```

Outcome:

```
[('Germany', '2005')", ('UK', '1298'), ('France', '1222'), ('Italy', '3990')]
```

So I'm close but I have no idea how to format it properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there, you just need to use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> ["{} ({})".format(x,y) for x,y in zip(Countries, Base)]
['Germany (2005)', 'UK (1298)', 'France (1222)', 'Italy (3990)']
```

Use `str.join`:

```
>>> print ", ".join('"{} ({})"'.format(x,y) for x,y in zip(Countries, Base))
"Germany (2005)", "UK (1298)", "France (1222)", "Italy (3990)"
```

Use `itertools.izip` for memory efficient solution.

Comment: That works but the output is still a list. Is there a way to present it a string?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 You can use a for loop to print each element in the list, or use `join()` has Ashwini has pointed out

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Ashwini's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17339608/1907098), you can take advantage of the implicit zipping that [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) performs on its arguments.

```
>>> ', '.join(map('"{} ({})"'.format, Countries, Base))
'"Germany (2005)", "UK (1298)", "France (1222)", "Italy (3990)"'
```

---

`timeit` results indicate that this solution is faster that the one proposed by Ashwini:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer as t
>>> t(lambda: ', '.join(map('"{} ({})"'.format, Countries, Base))).timeit()
4.5134528969464
>>> t(lambda: ", ".join(['"{} ({})"'.format(x,y) for x,y in zip(Countries, Base)])).timeit()
6.048398679161739
>>> t(lambda: ", ".join('"{} ({})"'.format(x,y) for x,y in zip(Countries, Base))).timeit()
8.722563482230271
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought this would be a slower solution, but it's actually faster (when I time it). + 1

Comment: That is actually pretty cool to see how long each function/script takes.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses map but forgoes string formatting in favor of another join and string concatenation:

```
print ', '.join(map(lambda a: ' ('.join(a)+')', zip(Countries, Base))) #outputs string

print map(lambda a: ' ('.join(a)+')', zip(Countries, Base)) #outputs list
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
','.join([Countries[i]+'('+Base[i]+')' for i in range(len(Countries))])
```